# nginx response or sample time vs latency vs connect time with jmeter

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nginx, latency, response-time

I have a pretty good nginx configuration and I am trying to test the load for **1000 requests in 10 seconds** for loading index.html page from nginx with https connection.
**For all the 1000 samples, latency and connect time is consistent**. But the response time is ok for the first few samples, but its really really bad for the remaining samples. I am attaching the samples. Please see the first screenshot. You can see the entries are consistent. **But in 2nd screenshot, you can find the response time getting larger and larger as it progresses**.
**What could be the reason for this?????**

- is it because of the hardware port limit ( 32000 - 61000 ) ?  But
  for virtual hosted machine, I am not allowed to edit this.
- is there any file descriptor open limit for virtual hosted machine?
  You can see that I set ulimit -a and -n to be around 200000. Will
  this work for a virtual machine?
- Do I have to make anymore adjustment in nginx configuration to make
  the response time consistent ?
- I am trying this HTTPS connection, is it b/c of the fact that each
  connection taking time in encryption and system getting busy with cpu
  cycles ? I am just trying to understand whether the problem is in
  hardware / software level ?

**My Hardware is Virtual Hosted. Below is the configuration**

- Architecture: x86_64
- CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order: Little Endian
- CPU(s): 16
- Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
- CPU family: 6
- Model: 26
- Stepping: 5
- CPU MHz: 2266.802
- BogoMIPS: 4533.60
- Virtualization: VT-x

**This is the nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxxx;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxxx;

    location / {     
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;  
    }   

    ## default location ##
    location @backend {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass    http://glassfish_servers;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    #proxy_redirect off;

    # set headers
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                     ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;                   

}
```

[image]

[image]

This is the aggregate report I collected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not nginx issue. Depending on how you configure JMeter the load may be much higher than you expect it to be.

I would recommend the following: as 1000 requests per 10 seconds is 100 requests/second,

1. Add Thread Group with

   - Threads: ~300
   - Ramp-up: 30
   - Loop count: Forever
   - Scheduler -> Duration -> i.e. 240 seconds
2. Add HTTP Request to hammer index.html
3. Add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/throughput-constant-timer) to limit the load to 100 requests / second - it will be 6000 requests per minute
4. Provide JMeter enough Java HEAP space - depending on your OS locate the following line in `jmeter` or `jmeter.bat` file:

   ```
   HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
   ```

   and adjust values to start with 50% and end with 80% of your total physical RAM
5. Run JMeter [in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with all listeners disabled like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
   ```
6. Once test finishes open JMeter GUI, add listener of your choice ([Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) is quite good) and analyse results

You can also take a look into [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project, it provides i.e. [PerfMon Metrics Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) so you will be able to monitor your server health during the load test and a number of extended graphs to visualise your test or [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) which is a wrapper on JMeter and other load testing tools which simplifies configuration and execution processes and makes results analysis easier.

Comment: I am trying this Dmitri. I will check this and come back to you

Comment: Average is 0.5s which should be fine. For those which run 15s - you need to investigate the cause.

Comment: what could be the reason for delay?